# Magento layout file not called?

Tags: magento2, php, database, nginx, ubuntu

This is my Controller Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Hikmadh\Menu\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory  */
protected $resultPageFactory;
public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
     \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
     $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
     parent::__construct($context);
}
/**
* Load the page defined in view/adminhtml/layout/samplenewpage_sampleform_index.xml
*
* @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
*/
public function execute()
{
     $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
     $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Add Products'));
     return $resultPage;
}
}
```

routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="hello_menu" frontName="hello_menu">
            <module name="Hello_Menu"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

hello_menu_product_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
   
</head>
<body>
     <referenceContainer name="content">
         <uiComponent name="products"/>
     </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

My problem is there is no layout exist while call this action? If anyone know the answer please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace controller this path :

```
namespace Hikmadh\Menu\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;
```

with

```
namespace Hello\Menu\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;
```

Because your medule name is : `Hello_Menu`

Answer (score 0):

you need to change in **Index.php** controller **namespace** :

```
namespace Hikmadh\Menu\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;
```

replace with

```
namespace Hello\Menu\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also your controller should extend `\Magento\Backend\App\Action`, not the frontend controller `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`.

HTH, Tom